# TypeError: res.render is not a function esto porque es devido

Tags: nodejs, express, express-session

hola tengo un crud que estoy haciendo y me sale en pantalla del navegado el erro
que me dice lo siguiente:

```
TypeError: res.render is not a function
at router.get (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\src\routes\authentication.js:5:9)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (C:\Users\A\Desktop\proyecto-trenes\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Deduzco y estoy pensando que puede ser de la documentacion actualizado pero creo que no es mi codigo del index.js es

```js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session');

const { database } = require('./keys');
//initializations
const app = express();

//setting

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers: require('./lib/handlebars')
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
//MIDDLEWARES
app.use(session({
    secret: 'faztmysqlenodesession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MySQLStore(database)
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());


//GLOBAL VARIABLES
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    app.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    next();
});

//ROUTES
app.use(require('./routes'));
app.use(require('./routes/authentication'));
app.use('/links', require('./routes/links'));

//PUBLIC
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//STARTING  THE SERVER

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

y el codigo de la rutas es :

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/signup', (res, req) => {
    res.render('auth/signup');
});

router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

});

module.exports = router;
```

porque me sale este error. gracias ante mano

Comment: En donde pones: `router.get('/signup', (res, req)` está mal. Debe ser `(req, res)` lo tienes al revés. ;) Saludos

Comment: Gracia Mauricio Contreras ya lo cambié y es verdad la sintaxis

Comment: Me alegra. Saludos